# How can build agents in Azure Pipelines be monitored for general performance metrics (CPU/disk/memory usage)?

Tags: monitoring, azure

TeamCity has the Performance Monitor feature (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/performance-monitor.html and https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/teamcity-performance-monitor/). Is there a suitable extension or other low-effort way to monitor basic metrics like CPU/disk/memory usage on a build agent which is running a job from Azure Pipelines? Ideally this would work for on-premise agents.